# How to send message headers with libsoup in Vala?

Tags: networking, vala

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to append the headers to my get request.

```
    var session = new Soup.Session ();
    
    var msg = new Soup.Message (
      "GET", 
      "some-api-key"
    );

    session.send_message (msg);

    print ("Message: %s", (string) msg.response_body.data);
```

I can't find any examples for how to do this. It's a miracle I made it this far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msg.request_headers.append ("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: It is the right answer, but it's also nice to include some resources, where OP can find more details, like [valadoc MessageHeaders](https://valadoc.org/libsoup-2.4/Soup.MessageHeaders.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry I answered my own question. I should have linked to some resources.